# Flattening TeamCity artefacts folder structure

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity (9.0.2) build configuration which contains the following artefact path pattern:

```
App\Agent\**\bin\%env.Configuration%\** => Deployment\AgentBuildPackage.%env.ApplicationVersion.EMX%.%system.build.number%.zip
```

which will create a file named something like AgentBuildPackage.4.5.0.185.zip in an artefact folder named Deployment

The current structure is like this:

- Deployment/
- AgentBuildPackage.4.5.0.185.zip/
- MyFirstServiceFolder/
- bin/
- Debug|Release/
- All the Files

The artefact archive contains all the folders it finds under App\Agent which is great. What I can't figure out is how to flatten those individual folders so they no longer contain the /bin/Release sub-folders.

What I want is

- Deployment/
- AgentBuildPackage.4.5.0.185.zip/
- MyFirstServiceFolder/
- All the Files

Can anyone tell me how please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify target folders within your target archive by using the `!` character after the name of the .zip file. Like this:

```
folderA\** => output.zip!/afolder/
```

Depending on how many service folders you have, this could be quite verbose, as you'll need to do it for each one, but it should do what you've described:

```
App\Agent\MyFirstServiceFolder\bin\%env.Configuration%\** => Deployment\AgentBuildPackage.%env.ApplicationVersion.EMX%.%system.build.number%.zip!/MyFirstServiceFolder/
```

Here's the documentation page on specifying artifact paths if you haven't seen it yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-PathsPatterns

Comment: Yes @CoderDennis that wouold indeed work at the cost of losing the wildcard inclusion of multiple folders and the need to explicitly define the folders. I also considered other ideas such as using an MSBuild task to change the structure prior to the artefact creation at the end of the build but in the balance this seems like the best approach. Thanks